# Calculating the percent of customers using product $X$ after long time

Tags: probability, limits, recurrence-relations

A company entered into a new market (sells product X) and started operating. In the first month of operation, it is found that  25% of customers are using the product X and while 75% of people still using other substitutes of X.

The company has it's own records as follows: (from other cities or etc.)

If somebody uses product X in current month, for him, there is 80% chance of keep using X in the next month, and 20% chance of switching to other substitute.

If somebody not using product X in current month, for him, there is 30% chance of using X in the next month, and 70% chance of not changing to X.

Find the % of customers using the product X after a long time.

---

**My Aproach/Attempt:**

Let us define abbreviations for the following:

Using the product X $\Rightarrow$ UPX

Using the the other Substitutes of X $\Rightarrow$ OSX

Keep using the product X in the next month $\Rightarrow$ KUPMX

Switch to other product  $\Rightarrow$ SWOP

Given

$P\left ( UPX \right )=0.25$,$P\left ( KUPMX/UPX \right )=0.80$,

$P\left (SWOP/ UPX \right )=0.20$,$P\left ( KPX/\left ( UPX \right ){}' \right )=0.30$

Given question can be simplified to

$P\left ( UPX/KUPMX \right )=\left ( P\left ( KUPMX/UPX \right )*P\left ( UPX \right ) \right )/\left ( P\left ( KUPMX/UPX \right )*P\left ( UPX \right ) \right )+\left ( P\left ( KUPMX/\left ( UPX \right ){}' \right )*P\left ( UPX \right ) {}'\right )$

=$0.80*0.25/\left ( 0.80*0.25 \right )+\left ( 0.30*0.75 \right )=.4705$

=$47$%

Am I correct?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the work you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U_n$ be the event that a person uses the product in the $n$th month and let $\overline{U_n}$ be the complement. Then

\begin{align}
P(U_{n+1})&=P(U_{n+1}|U_n)P(U_n)+P(U_{n+1}|\overline{U_n})P(\overline{U_n})\\
&=0.8P(U_n)+0.3P(\overline{U_n})\\
&=0.8P(U_n)+0.3(1-P(U_n)),
\end{align}

with $P(U_1)=0.25,$ which is a linear recursion. It can be solved to give 
$$P(U_n)=\frac{6-7\times2^{-n}}{10},$$
which, in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$, gives $\frac{6}{10}=0.6$.

Comment: Is my logic incorrect? @Lovsovs

Comment: @sourav Yes. I get 0.6 as the final answer. I think what you have tried to do is calculated the probability after one month, not after "many" (which I read as infinitely many) months.

Comment: Your answer is perfect !its 0.6 only !i am not getting how to calculate probablity for "many " month ...can you please ellaborate your answer :)

Comment: @sourav Fair enough, but do you know something about recurrence relations? If not, I would read up on that first.

Comment: yes  i know ! you please ellaborate your answer :)

Comment: @sourav Great, yeah sure, just a sec :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46092/discussion-between-sourav-and-lovsovs).